# ASP.NET Core how do you format dates by a visitors localisation?

Tags: asp.net-core

As the title suggests, I wish to format dates in my ASP.NET Core app so that they are formatted for the visitor's region.

For example, in my view model I define my date like this currently;

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MMM dd, yyyy}")]
public DateTime OpenDate { get; set; }
```

How do I configure my application to use the visitors local preference?

I have tried to enable localisation within my startup file by placing the following before useMvc();

```
app.UseRequestLocalization();
```

Then in my controller I have tried the following, but the value of browserCulture is always EMPTY unless I edit my startup file and configure a default culture.

```
var locale = Request.HttpContext.Features.Get<IRequestCultureFeature>();
var browserCulture = locale.RequestCulture.UICulture.ToString();
```

I'm defining a default culture using;

```
services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-GB");
            });
```

I've have used Chrome to check that my browser is passing across the Accept-Language header, and I can confirm it is. Using a Chrome plugin I have also altered the Accept-Language property to be different to the default culture setup in the application i.e. en-US, but that doesn't get picked up either.

What am I missing?

----- RESOLUTION -----

As suggested, I needed to configure the cultures that the application was going to support. I altered the configuration of localisation in ConfigureServices in my startup file to the following;

```
// Setup supported cultures
            var supportedCultures = new[]
            {
                new CultureInfo("en-US"),
                new CultureInfo("fr"),
                new CultureInfo("en-GB"),
                new CultureInfo("zh-TW")
            };
            services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-GB");
                options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
                options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you didn't add support cultures for `RequestLocalizationOptions`:

```
var supportedCultures = new[]
{
    new CultureInfo("en-US"),
    new CultureInfo("fr"),
    new CultureInfo("en-GB"),
    new CultureInfo("zh-TW"),
    // ...
};

app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
{
    DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-GB"),
    SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
    SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
});
```

Comment: Ah do you have to specifically specify which cultures you're going to support? I just assumed they would all be supported by default? I will try this.

Comment: @SheppardDigital Yes. I did give it a try to not configure the supportedCultures manually, and it didn't work for me. I haven't dived into the source code to research the reason, but I guess that's the case: we have to add supported cultures manually.

Comment: @SheppardDigital According to the [source code](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Middleware/Localization/src/RequestLocalizationMiddleware.cs#L94-L118), we must ensure the `SupportedCultures` not empty to support multiple cultures. I don't see there's default culture added for `IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions> options.SupportedCultures` within the source code.  So I believe in order to support multiple cultures, we have to configure it manually.